# Can't remove child from parent node

Tags: javascript

Hey friends I'm using window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1300px)"); to add some divs to the DOM when the screen width is less than 1300px, Then I need to remove them when the screen width goes back over 1300px. I'm getting an error in my console saying the node I'm trying to remove isn't a child. But it is?? Any Ideas?

line 75
https://jsfiddle.net/hby2rn13/

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right');
const img = document.querySelector('.image-slider');
const width = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1300px)");
let num = 1;

adjustMenuDesign();
window.addEventListener('resize', adjustMenuDesign);

function adjustMenuDesign() {
 const tostadas = document.querySelector('.tostadas');
 const tostadasRow = document.querySelector('.tostadas-row');
 const tortas = document.querySelector('.tortas');
 const tortasRow = document.querySelector('.tortas-row');
 const columnRight = document.querySelector('.column-right .column');
 const menu = document.querySelector('.menu-section');
 const columnWrap = document.createElement('div');
 const column = document.createElement('div');
 const tacos = document.querySelector('.column-right .tacos');
 const nodesToRemove = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

    if (width.matches) { // If media query matches
     columnRight.removeChild(tortas);
     columnRight.removeChild(tostadas);
     columnRight.removeChild(tostadasRow);
     columnRight.removeChild(tortasRow);
     column.appendChild(tostadas);
     column.appendChild(tostadasRow);
     column.appendChild(tortas);
     column.appendChild(tortasRow);
     column.classList.add('column');
     columnWrap.classList.add('column-new');
     columnWrap.appendChild(column);
     menu.appendChild(columnWrap);
     removeNodes(nodesToRemove);
 } else {
  putNodesBack(nodesToRemove);
  menu.removeChild(columnWrap);
  columnRight.appendChild(tortas);
     columnRight.appendChild(tostadas);
     columnRight.appendChild(tostadasRow);
     columnRight.appendChild(tortasRow);
 }

 function removeNodes(nodes) {
  for(let i = nodes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   tacos.removeChild(nodes[i]);
  } 
 }

 function putNodesBack(nodes) {
  for(let i = nodes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   tacos.appendChild(nodes[i]);
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: It doens't say it is not a child, it says it is not a child of the <menu> element

Comment: Instead of adding/removing DOM nodes why dont you just add/remove class that hides/unhides the content?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: this happens because it also makes the check when they are already removed.

Comment: @alessandrio Yah that's what I thought, any ideas on a fix?

Comment: @alessandrio Do I even need an else statement? I mean it's only purpose is to adjust it back for a larger width. The only people who are gonna do that are the users messing with it in the devtools. A user with a smaller screen will just see the adjusted version anyways

Comment: no, when deleting your element you cannot bring it back obviously this makes the error appear, I advise you to change that (`.removeChild(`/`.appendChild(`) to `.style.display=['block/hide']`

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure this is what you are trying to accomplish but as I went through your fiddle (as you highlighted line 75) I found that you are trying to remove a div element inside class 'menu-section' the problem here is you have more than one div element inside class 'menu-section' you need to specify which div you want to remove per say give that div some class name or id and select the specific one to remove or you can call an index value like `menu.removeChild(columnWarp[0])` you can try this. hope this is what you are expecting.

For more please refer [Remove all the child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-the-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript/)

Example

```html
<div class="parent"></div>

<button onClick="create();">add</button>
<button onClick="createFoo();">add Foo element</button>
<button onClick="remove();">remove created div</button>
<button onClick="removeTd();">remove selected div</button>

<script>
function create() {
const columnWrap = document.createElement('div');
columnWrap.innerHTML = 'Empty div no id';
const menu = document.querySelector('.parent');
menu.appendChild(columnWrap);
}
function remove() {
const columnWrap = document.createElement('div');
columnWrap.innerHTML = 'Empty div no id';
const menu = document.querySelector('.parent');
menu.appendChild(columnWrap);
if(confirm("Are you sure??")){
menu.removeChild(columnWrap);
}
}
function createFoo() {
const columnWrap = document.createElement('div');
columnWrap.innerHTML = 'Empty div with id foo';
columnWrap.id ="foo";
const menu = document.querySelector('.parent');
menu.appendChild(columnWrap);

}
function removeTd() {

const menu = document.querySelector('.parent');
const delElement = document.querySelector('#foo');
if(confirm("Are you sure??")){
menu.removeChild(delElement);
}

}
</script>
```

Happy Coding <3 !
Thanks

Comment: I do specify the div I want removed. It's called 'columnWrap' and it's gets appended when the screen is less than 1300px just fine. So if I can append I should be able to remove it. using menu.removeChild(columnWrap);

Comment: yes columnWrap is a div element but when you append one more div inside menu it works if you want to get the same div using the same query selector it doesn't work that way you need choose a specifc element to select with the class name or id attributes

Comment: @spabsa please check my example snippet on my answer